# Set Friday as Weekend day in moment()

Tags: node.js, momentjs, moment-timezone

**Is there any way to set "Friday" as a weekend day in moment() globally.**

I am using moment and moment-business plugin in node.js

I need to consider 3 days as Weekend (**Friday, Saturday and Sunday**) and 4 days as Weekday (**Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday**).

```
const moment = require('moment');
const business = require('moment-business');
```

Comment: Perhaps using [`moment-business-days`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-business-days#use-localization-to-configure-business-days)?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-business-days only support above node version 12.30

Comment: Thanks guys, https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-business-days working for me ;)